# Null Pointer Exception in AWS lambda without any stacktrace

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, nullpointerexception, aws-lambda, aws-java-sdk

I have created an AWS Lambda. In cloud watch I can see the Null pointer exception without any stacktrace. All I can see is the below exception and I'm not really sure where it's happening.

For sure the exception is throwing before coming to the `handleRequest` method. Just after constructor processing. But the lambda is working fine as expected.

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
```

Code:

```
public class Hello implements RequestHandler<Object, String> {

    public void Hello(SNSevent snsEvent){
      this.snsEvent = snsEvent;
    }

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {


        // TODO: implement your handler
        return "Hello from Lambda";
    }

}
```

Can anyone suggest what's happening here?

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc As said in the question, the exception is coming up just before coming to the handle request part

Comment: Try remove the constructor taking a parameter. It's preventing Lambda from instantiating your handler.

Comment: At any rate, you are supposed to get the incoming event from the context instead of the constructor.

Comment: @jingx well. After the exception the lamba is coming to the handleRequest part and exceuting as expected. the issue here is not really sure why the npe is coming up.